# How to upload "one" image to a database with Entity Framework and MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, razor

I am trying to write an image upload service for my `PostController` in the `Create` action, however I am getting a compile error saying:

> 'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'InputStream'/ContentLength and no
>   extension method 'InputStream'/ContentLength accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.Array'

On these lines:

```
    using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(uploadImage.InputStream))
    {
        imageData = binaryReader.ReadBytes(uploadImage.ContentLength);
    }
```

I only want to upload one file and no more. I am also unsure if this is correct: `singlepart/form-data` in the `Html.Begin` form.

I did try `HttpPostedFileBase uploadImage` instead of `HttpPostedFileBase[] uploadImage` however I got an error of `instance is not set to an object` on this line:

```
using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(uploadImage.InputStream))
```

It should be noted that `post.Picture` is `(varbinary(max))` in my Post table.

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Post", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "singlepart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>

            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Picture)

            <div class="editor-field">
                <input type="file" name="uploadImages" class="input-files" />
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Picture)
            </div>
        </div>
```

Controller:

```
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "BlogUserEmail,CategoryId,Title,ShortDescription,Description")]Post post, HttpPostedFileBase[] uploadImage, string selectedTags)
    {
        if (uploadImage != null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Create");
        }

        byte[] imageData = null;

        using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(uploadImage.InputStream)) // not set to an instance of an object
        {
            imageData = binaryReader.ReadBytes(uploadImage.ContentLength);
        }
        var Image = new Post
        {
             Picture = imageData
        };

        post.Picture = Image.Picture;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this error because you have an `Array` of objects and you try to use `ContentLength`/`InputStream` which is a property of `HttpPostedFileBase`

Instead of `uploadImage.InputStream` you can take first element if you try tu upload just 1 image `uploadImage[0].InputStream` or `uploadImage.First().InputStream`. Or instead you can remove `[]`.

Also you have to change `enctype` from `"singlepart/form-data"` to `"multipart/form-data"`

The input have the **name** `uploadImages` and the parameter of the action `uploadImage`, change the input according

```
<input type="file" name="uploadImage" class="input-files" />
```

---

I **recommend** you to use a model that will encapsulate all form elements.

```
public class PostCreateModel : Post
{
    public HttpPostedFileBase uploadImage { get; set; }
    public string selectTags { get; set; }
}
```

And Action will look like this. Don't forget to change `@model` in View.

```
public ActionResult Create(PostCreateModel post)
{
    if (post.uploadImage != null)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Create");
    }

    byte[] imageData = null;

    using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(post.uploadImage.InputStream)) // not set to an instance of an object
    {
        imageData = binaryReader.ReadBytes(post.uploadImage.ContentLength);
    }
    var Image = new Post
    {
         Picture = imageData
    };

    post.Picture = Image.Picture;
```

Comment: With those changes I still get the error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. on the uploadImage[0].InputStream line...

Comment: Picture is set to public byte[] Picture { get; set; } in my model Post

Comment: Doing it your way will still causes the object reference issue. If I do it in another model or I do it in the action directly it makes no difference.

Comment: @GarrithGraham See my update, you have `uploadImages` instead of `uploadImage`.

Comment: Yeah that fixed the object reference however now I have another issue, nothing is in my database... :( ty tho for the help

Comment: @GarrithGraham you wellcome :), for that i have to see how you saved in your database, but is another question.

Answer (score 1):

You are correctly worried about `singlepart/form-data`, since it is not valid encoding method. Html forms support following encodings:

- application/x-www-form-urlencoded (the default)
- multipart/form-data (allows posting of files)
- text/plain

So you have to use `multipart/form-data` to post files.

Then you can modify `Create` method to only accept single `HttpPostedFileBase`"

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "BlogUserEmail,CategoryId,Title,ShortDescription,Description")]Post post, HttpPostedFileBase uploadImage, string selectedTags)
```